# Correcting this segmentation fault

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

I'm working through this example in C and my Debian(64-bit Kali) distribution keeps saying this causes a segmentation fault and won't run it.  I'd like to fix this so I can run it and keep learning assembly.  Here's my command:

```
gcc -ggdb -mpreferred-stack-boundary=2 -fno-stack-protector -o Simple SimpleDemo.c
```

Source:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int add(int x, int y)
{
    int z =10;

    z = x + y;
    return z;
}

main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int a = atoi(argv[1]);
    int b = atoi(argv[2]);
    int c;
    char buffer[100];

    gets(buffer);
    puts(buffer);

    c = add(a,b);

    printf("Sum of %d+%d = %d\n",a, b, c);
    exit(0);
}
```

Comment: What's on your standard input?

Comment: Did you supply two arguments? The program needs them, but does not check they exist.

Comment: Along with what Kerrek said, this program REQUIRES two arguments.  `./prog 123 345` then type some data for the `gets` and it should give you a sum.  Most other command arguments (non-numeric etc) will give you garbage or segfaults.

Comment: the 'gets()' function should never be used, as it always allows major problems like buffer overrun.  use 'fgets()' instead

Comment: this does not compile cleanly because of the argc not being used. cause a warning to be raised.

Comment: @user3629249 with gcc 4.6.3 on my server, it compiles with no warnings, and even with `-Wall` it only give the return type warning `warning: return type defaults to 'int' [-Wreturn-type]`

Comment: Hey everyone, thanks a lot for the responses.  I should have mentioned, this program is supposed to be written poorly and it's being used as a tool to see what happens during a buffer overflow using GDB.  I'm a tool and just didn't put in any input, and that caused the segmentation fault.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you supply two arguments? The program needs them, but does not check they exist. If you run the program with no arguments, that will probably cause a segfault.

If this was a serious example I would throw away the book and look elsewhere. The `main()` function has no return type. It does not check for program arguments. It has a superfluous buffer read and write. It uses `exit()` where it is normal to use `return`. The function `add()` assigns a value to `z` before over writing it. Here is the code cleaned up, but it would still be better to use `strtol()` than `atoi()`.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int add(int x, int y)
{
    int z = x + y;
    return z;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int a, b, c;
    if (argc < 3)
    {
        printf ("Need two arguments\n");
        return 1;
    }
    a = atoi(argv[1]);
    b = atoi(argv[2]);
    c = add(a,b);
    printf("Sum of %d+%d = %d\n",a, b, c);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Good answer but doesn't answer the question.

Comment: @zenith thank you, I forgot to reproduce the earlier comment.

Comment: The original program is meant to be used as a learning tool.  We're using GDB to see what happens during a buffer overflow.  You got it though, I didn't supply two arguments >.<

Comment: @AsaHunt if you want to prevent buffer overflow in the code I deleted, you need `if (fgets(buffer, 100, stdin) != NULL) {...}`. If you liked my answer please "accept" it!

Answer (score 0):

```
the following is a method of writing the program.
it cleanly compiles/runs
is properly checks for the right number of command line parameters
it properly declares main() as returning int
it properly returns from main, rather than 
   calling exit() (which aborts the program)

#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int add(int x, int y)
{
    int z = x + y;

    return z;
} // end function: add


int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    if( 3 != argc )
    {
        printf( "\nusage; %s value1 value2\n", argv[0] );
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }

    // implied else, correct number of parameters

    int a = atoi(argv[1]);
    int b = atoi(argv[2]);
    int c;
    char buffer[100];

    if( fgets(buffer, sizeof buffer, stdin) )
    { // then, fgets successful
        puts(buffer);
    }

    c = add(a,b);

    printf("Sum of %d+%d = %d\n",a, b, c);
    return 0;
} // end function: main
```

Comment: Thank you for the proper example!  I may use this in the future.